# AWS CLI command to list the roles and accounts I have access to

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

Suppose the administrator has created accounts `Acc-A, Acc-B, Acc-C`
Suppose the administrator has created roles `Role-A, Role-B, Role-C`

I know with my AWS access key and secret key I can switch to `Acc-A @ Role-A` and `Acc-B @ Role-B` but I do not know that the `Acc-C` exists.

My requirement is how can i list all the `accounts` i have access to and how can i list all the `roles` i have access to?

I have tried the following but both of them give that i do not have sufficient permission.

```sh
aws iam list-account-aliases
aws iam list-roles
```

Comment: You can't do this. If you don't know that `Acc-C` exists there is no way for you to check if you have access to it.

Comment: Ah okay.  Thanks a lot @Marcin. Shouldn't there be a way that tell a user all the roles he can assume and all the accounts he has access to ?

Comment: [AWS IAM Access Analyzer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/what-is-access-analyzer.html) can sort of provide that information, but it is not intended for "telling a user what they have access to".

Comment: Maybe there should, but assuming a role is only way of getting access to other account.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Not sure what do you mean. The analyzed provides the opposite information - who/what can access my or my org resources, not what I can access in any other account in AWS.

Comment: Correct. It provides that general "who can access" information, but not from a user viewpoint.